# make file still readable after hashing in python

Tags: python

I'm having this hash function for hashing an image with a new name:

```
def get_file_hash(file):
    """
    Returns a new filename based on the file content using MD5 hashing.
    It uses hashlib.md5() function from Python standard library to get
    the hash.

    Parameters
    ----------
    file : werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage
        File sent by user.

    Returns
    -------
    str
        New filename based in md5 file hash.
    """
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    basename = os.path.basename(file.filename)
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(basename)
    file_read = file.read()
    hasher.update(file_read)
    processed_filename = hasher.hexdigest() + extension

    return processed_filename
```

and I'm not passing the last evaluation of this test (the one which says "Check the file content is still readable!"):

```
 def test_get_file_hash(self):
        filename = "tests/dog.jpeg"
        md5_filename = "0a7c757a80f2c5b13fa7a2a47a683593.jpeg"
        with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
            file = FileStorage(fp)

            # Check the new filename is correct
            new_filename = utils.get_file_hash(file)
            self.assertEqual(md5_filename, new_filename, new_filename)

            # Check the file content is still readable!
            self.assertTrue(file.read() != b"")
```

I don't know how to make that happen after I call the function, in context I implement the hash function and then save the image:

```
filename = utils.get_file_hash(img_api)
img_api.save("static/uploads/" + filename)
```

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated,
best

Comment: Try "rewinding" the file stream after use: `file.stream.seek(0)`

Comment: What do you mean by "still readable"? Your test checks the position of the file pointer in an open file. I wouldn't *expect* there to be anything left to read once you've hashed it.

Comment: Also, there's doesn't seem to be a compelling reason to pass a file object to `get_file_hash` at all; it would suffice to provide it a `bytes` value (consisting of the data to hash, independent of where that data came from) and a file extension to use to create the file name to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you very much Mathias! this is how the function finally pass the test just in case:

```
def get_file_hash(file):
    """
    Returns a new filename based on the file content using MD5 hashing.
    It uses hashlib.md5() function from Python standard library to get
    the hash.

    Parameters
    ----------
    file : werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage
        File sent by user.

    Returns
    -------
    str
        New filename based in md5 file hash.
    """
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    basename = os.path.basename(file.filename)
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(basename)
    file_read = file.read()
    hasher.update(file_read)
    processed_filename = hasher.hexdigest() + extension
    file.stream.seek(0)

    return processed_filename
```